# Obtener informacion de un div sin id con BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Nesecito hallar el codigo de este HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

                <br>
                <div class="control-group">

                    <div class="controls">
                        <!--                    <span class="icon32 icon-green icon-undo" title="atras" onclick="atras();"></span> -->
                        <a class="well span3 top-block"><img class="grayscale" src="/SimonQuotation/images/icons/cars.png">
                            <div>
                                Marca : ---------- SA <br> Codigo : 1601224
                            </div></a> <a class="well span3 top-block"><img class="grayscale" src="/images/icons/keys.png">
                            <div>Modelo : ----</div></a> <a class="well span3 top-block"><img class="grayscale"
</div>
```

¿Alguien sabe como acceder a el ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL codigo para realizar Scraping con beuatiful mediante su clase:

```
codigo= soup.find("div", {"class":"controls"}).div
```

Gracias por ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo la documentación me doy cuenta que puedes buscarlo directamente por la clase con este método `soup.div['name_class']`